# Behavior driven development with Docker

Tags: testing

I have a drupal8 site running in docker environment. I want to make some bdd test with Behat.
My **behat.yml** file looks like:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      base_url: http://mysite.test
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      api_driver: 'drupal'
      drupal:
        drupal_root: '/home/desktop/Projects/mysite/app/web'
      region_map:
        header: "#header"
```

And my **.feature** file:

```
@api
Feature: Test account menu links

  Scenario: Make sure that logged in users see the account menu
    Given I am logged in as a user with the "authenticated" role
    And I am on "/"
    Then I should see the link "My account" in the "header" region
    And I should see the link "Log out" in the "header" region
```

I am using the Drupal API driver but I get an error of

> Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY'.

I think this means it can't access my database, but what else should I define in my Behat file or in my `docker-compose.yml` file? I have tested a story when access is not required, e.g. a contact page submission and that goes smoothly.

Comment: That error means that the pdo_mysql extension is missing from the PHP installation. Not sure how you would fix that, depends on your docker config I guess

Comment: @Clive If I look at my phpinfo then pdo_mysql is there and enabled. But what else could be missing?

Comment: I don't know - the error you've got there is the result of what I already mentioned, to the best of my knowledge there's no way to get that error if the pdo_mysql extension is installed and enabled

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the right php.ini, you could have a different one for the CLI and web

Comment: When I was using a selenium docker image I had to specify the container name as the host and not the site url.